# How can I see all facilities available to build with no spaces free?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

It's easy to see which facilities you can build when you have a space clear in your base - you simply click that space.  But if I have no spaces free (or am waiting for spaces to be cleared out), how can I see which buildings I have available to build (and their costs etc) at that instant in time?

Comment: This is a good question...  I don't think it's possible though :(  Perhaps someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: I've been wondering this very thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. You can save, demolish a facility (it is instant), check the list and reload.

Comment: Does ironman mode compromise this possibility?

Comment: @M'vy apart from the save and reload bit, no.